# How create Hyperledger fabric keypairs similar crytogen using fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I observed that the cryptogen use the different config-file.yaml compare to fabric CA.

```
1. why cryptogen config file is different compare to fabric CA
2. How i can generate keypairs and certificate similar to cryptogen using fabric ca
```

Comment: References for your 2nd question: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html#fabric-ca-operations-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cryptogen` is a standalone tool provided by hyperledger fabric for testing purposes 
It will come with pre-generated certificates and keys, in order to give instructions on what to generate and how, we can give instructions through config file.

on the other hand, `fabric-ca` aims to fulfil the  certificate authority needs, the config file for fabri-ca is to give instruction to setup fabric-ca

> Both config files are different and have different purposes.

If you curious how cryptogen is generating predefined certificates then you will have to look into x.509 go package, **cryptogen** tool is built with **golang** and by using of **x.509** package

https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/

Comment: thank you for replay, any demo or example is available to create keypair, using Fabric CA, which i can create same folder structure like cryptogentool.

Comment: Once you have fabric-ca up and running then you can connect through nodejs sdk, javasdk or cli and follow https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html#fabric-ca-operations-guide

Comment: Download fabric-ca client if you choose CLI

Comment: i had one doubt, what is difference between two methods Identity service and register User?

Comment: Using identity service you can register user